# Difference between manage and write in Openldap acl

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I'm currently studying `openldap` ACL.

[In this documentation](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html), at chapter `8.3.3. The access to grant`
there is a `manage` keyword that does gives more rights than the `write` keyword.

Do you know what is the difference between each ? And when to choose one instead of the other ? There seems to be no explanations.